# Using quaternion value for mouse events

Tags: mouse, quaternions

I am having a quaternion value `Quaternion(0.55084228515625, -0.05267333984375, 0.11297607421875, 0.8251953125)`. How can I use this for mouse movements.

The quaternion value is of the format `a+bi+cj+dk`since its 3D value but the mouse uses value format  `dx,dy` which is 2D. So is there a way to map quaternion value to the mouse.

Answer (score 0):

Quaternions typically describe a rotation rather than a translation. Basically our problem here is then that we have a 3D rotation and need to convert it into an X, Y displacement for our mouse. There are many different ways you could approach this, however my first thought would be to consider a laser pointer that you rotate about a fixed point and somewhere in front of it is a projector screen. If you apply a rotation to the laser pointer, you can then measure the distance the spot of light travels.

To bring some math to the table, we'll represent the laser pointer as a 3D vector:

```
P = (0,0,1)
```

Quaternions however have 4 components because they contain an additional degree of freedom compared to a vector, so we must add an additional dimension to our vector if we want to do math with it. As quaternions typically use imaginary components i, j, and k to represent the x, y, and z dimensions and a real component for magnitude (bit of a simplification), we shall represent our point as:

```
P = (0, 0i, 0j, 1k)
```

You stated the quaternion you have is `Q = (0.5508, -0.0526i, 0.1129j, 0.8251k)`, but we also will need its conjugate which simply multiplies the imaginary components by -1: `Q' = (0.5508, 0.0526i, -0.1129j, -0.8251k)`

In order to perform the rotation we multiply the quaternion and the point by eachother then that result by the conjugate of the quaternion using the [Hamilton product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quaternion#Hamilton_product)

```
new_P = Hamilton(Hamilton(Q, P) , Q').
```

You should now have a vector in 3d space that has been rotated by some amount, in which you could either [project](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scalar_projection) to get your coordinates on a flat plane, or you could simply just assume a spherical projection screen and not transform the x or y components at all simply taking them as-is. If the angle is typically small the difference between the two will be minimal.

**Something to consider:**

If you always start with the same input vector, you can vastly simplify the math because you know certain components are always 0. For my example if you start with `(0,0,0,1)` and quaternion: `(a, b, c, d)` the rotated vector is:

```
(0, 2ac + 2bd, 2cd - 2ad, a2-b2-c2+d2)
```

If you only need a change in x and y for each rotation you can even get rid of the z component to get just: `(2ac + 2bd, 2cd - 2ad)`.